# xp:inputText and multipleSeparator only worsk for multipla values entered

Tags: java, jsf, xpages

I have a xp:inputText element with property ultipleSeparator=","

The inputText has as databinding value="#{customerBean.customer.groupMail}"

The field for the customer object is defined as followed:

```
private List<String> groupMail = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When I enter multiple values and submit, the values are properly stored on the Notes document. But when I submit just a single value then I get a warning message:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461575/785061

Comment: Yes I found it. thank you!